# Are Risk 2210 A.D 3.0 MODs considered as 1 unit or 3 units?

Tags: risk

In the rules it says you can trade three 1.0 MOD for one 3.0 MOD and that the 3.0 MOD is worth 3 **armies**.
In the rules of Invading territories you roll 1, 2 or 3 dice, and you must have atleast one more **unit** than the number of dice you roll.

If I have one 1.0 MOD and one 3.0 MOD and attacks, is that 1 or 3 dice rolls?
Or are **armies** and **units** different in the context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Risk 2210 uses the same base rules as classic Risk.

From the rulebook, page 2:

> If you have a question not answered in the  RISK 2210 A.D.™ section,
>   then refer to the Classic RISK® rules

In classic risk, "units" and "armies" are synonymous.  The higher denomination pieces are just for player convenience.  Thus, with a 1.0-MOD and a 3.0-MOD, you would roll 3 dice on the attack, just the same as if you had four 1.0-MOD's.

Comment: 4 dice? I assume a typo or I have miss interpreted something again as I though 3 dices were the maximum for the attacker?

Comment: @Wgaffa yep, that was a typo